# How can I use a variable inside a --command option in gcloud ssh

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, ssh, gcloud

`gcloud compute ssh --zone ZONE INSTANCE --command 'bin/bash deploy.sh master'`

In the above command, I running a script called deploy.sh which accepts git branch name as a parameter(master).

But I get the branch name as a variable in jenkins and I want to use that variable name instead of hardcoding master.

For example,

```
branch_name="xyz"
gcloud compute ssh --zone ZONE INSTANCE --command 'bin/bash deploy.sh branch_name'
```

Is there any way to do this? I am really stuck to this point.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
branch_name="xyz"
gcloud compute ssh --zone ZONE INSTANCE --command "bin/bash deploy.sh $branch_name"
```